# A sliding window algorithm applied to timestamps instead of indexes in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I've encountered a coding problem on my exam: on my input I'm having a .csv file with rows of trade transactions data of 4 columns:

```
09:30:01.034,   36.99,  100,    V
09:30:11.034,   33.99,  205,    V
09:30:21.034,   36.99,  300,    V
09:30:21.334,   36.99,  76, V
09:30:21.534,   33.99,  100,    D
09:30:25.034,   36.99,  201,    V
09:30:28.034,   36.99,  202,    V
09:30:51.034,   36.99,  100,    D
09:31:01.554,   36.69,  120,    V
09:32:51.034,   36.99,  100,    D
09:33:01.034,   36.99,  99, V
09:33:05.734,   36.99,  100,    D
```

The first column values are second parts of their transactions' timestamps (*hh:mm:ss.mmm*); The fourth column represents a transaction's type; The second and the third ones you can just ignore, I suppose; The task is to develop an algorithm which will help us to find separately the maximum amount of V-transactions, and the maximum amount of D-transactions, which both have occured in some period(window) of one minute (not obligatory the same minute);

First of all, I did a search on Google for the sliding window algorithm problem, and I found this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/window-sliding-technique/ (*thanks to Prerna Saini for the Java version of the algorithm*)
I tried to implement the sliding window technique then, so *let me show you what I came up with*

```
public class NormalMinuteWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int WINDOW = 60000;
        List<TradeEntry> tradeInfo = new ArrayList<>();
        int bestResultV = 0, bestResultD = 0, localResultV, localResultD;
        NormalMinuteWindow app = new NormalMinuteWindow();
        app.readFile(tradeInfo);

        for (int i = 0; i < tradeInfo.size(); i++) {
            localResultD = 0;
            localResultV = 0;
            TradeEntry next = tradeInfo.get(i);
            int counter = i;
            long win = tradeInfo.get(i).getDate().getTime() + WINDOW;
            while (win > next.getDate().getTime()) {
                if (next.getExchange().equals(true)) {
                    localResultV++;
                } else {
                    localResultD++;
                }
                if (counter < tradeInfo.size() - 1) {
                    counter++;
                    next = tradeInfo.get(counter);
                } else break;
            }

            bestResultV = Math.max(localResultV, bestResultV);
            bestResultD = Math.max(localResultD, bestResultD);

        }

        System.out.println(bestResultV);
        System.out.println(bestResultD);

    }

    class TradeEntry {
        private Timestamp date;
        private Float price;
        private Short size;
        private Boolean exchange;

        public TradeEntry(Timestamp date, Float price, Short size, Boolean exchange) {
            this.date = date;
            this.price = price;
            this.size = size;
            this.exchange = exchange;
        }

        // all the necessary getters and setters, etc....
        // I know they are not necessary in an inner class, but usually
        // you wouldn't be using an inner class

    }

    private void readFile(List<TradeEntry> list) {
        String csvFile = "trades.csv";
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] tradeInfo = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                boolean exch;
                if (tradeInfo[3].toUpperCase().equals("V"))
                    exch = true;
                else exch = false;

                list.add(new TradeEntry(Timestamp.valueOf("2000-03-01 ".concat(tradeInfo[0])),
                        Float.parseFloat(tradeInfo[1]),
                        Short.parseShort(tradeInfo[2]),
                        exch));

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

However, my algorithm was said to be giving wrong results for max amount of "D"s and "V"s occured in some one minute. I have two questions here:

- Is my algorithm a sliding window algorithm actually?
- Where have I made a mistake, which produces wrong results, regardless of whether it is an O(m*n) or an O(n) algorithm?

Comment: Your window does not slide. You create it from scratch every time. What results do you get with the data set and what results do you expect?

Comment: @NicoSchertler okay, it is not a sliding window, then. However I'm still thinking of its complexity as of a sliding one O(n). Please correct me if I'm wrong. With the given set of data I'm getting 6 for "V"s and 2 for "D"s, which seems to be correct in accordance to the task. But the online exam system tells me "Wrong Answer"... And I cannot see what I did wrong.

Comment: It is wrong because it should be 7 V's. The 7th row of type V is exactly 60 seconds after the first one and should probably be included.